# Django email sending error

Tags: python, django, traceback

i'm trying to get a contact form on a personal site to work.
i'm using the smtp outlook. 
Right now it gives me the following error:

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: *******

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/Nmaster88/Ngranja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/Nmaster88/Ngranja/Ngranja/Ngranja/views.py" in sendmail
  23.             send_mail(request.POST['contactSubject'],"From: "+request.POST['contactEmail']+'\n\n'+request.POST['contactMessage'],request.POST['contactEmail'],['nunomaster_@hotmail.com'],)
File "/home/Nmaster88/Ngranja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.     return mail.send()
File "/home/Nmaster88/Ngranja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  303.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/home/Nmaster88/Ngranja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  100.             new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/home/Nmaster88/Ngranja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  58.             self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py" in __init__
  242.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py" in connect
  321.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  292.                                         self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py" in create_connection
  509.         raise err
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py" in create_connection
  500.             sock.connect(sa)

Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError at /
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

my settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

view file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render

def sendmail(request):
    errors=[]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('contactName',''):
            errors.append('Coloca um nome.')
        if not request.POST.get('contactEmail',''):
            errors.append('Coloca um email.')
        if not request.POST.get('contactSubject',''):
            errors.append('Coloca um assunto.')
        if not request.POST.get('contactMessage',''):
            errors.append('Coloca um assunto.')
        if not errors:
            subject=request.POST['contactSubject']
            email=request.POST['contactEmail']
            message=request.POST['contactMessage']
            send_mail(subject,"From: "+email+'\n\n'+message,email,['myemail@hotmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou/')
    return render(request, "mypage.html", {'errors': errors})
```

Does anyone has a clue on what is wrong?
If necessary i can give more info on the app

[EDIT]
I'm hosting the page at pythonanywhere.com, does the error have something to do with the server?

[EDIT] SOLVED
Pythonanywhere for free users only works for Gmail, and i had to give it permission for less secure apps! Now it works fine.

Comment: And if you open up a REPL, import smtplib, and attempt to connect to your  SMTP server can you get an actual connection ? Are you using a local exchange server or Office 365 ? Are you using TLS or SSL SNMP ?

Comment: Are you running into [their firewall](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers/)?

Comment: At their forums, they say, that only google gmail works. Im now using the gmail config. The error i have now it's another. I have a SMTPAuthenticationError.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `use_ssl=True` in your `SMTP` settings and changing the port to `465`.

You can directly refer to [Django SMTP options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/) for list of all the settings you can tweak.
Also please mention which Django version you are using for building your app?

Comment: Django Version: 1.8.1

Comment: yes i tried, still no success, maybe i did something wrong i don't know.

Comment: Have you tried using core python mail. Try using these settings first in core python mail `smtplib` class.