# Django contact form not sending email

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms, contact-form

I have a simple contact form set up on my about page, and after filling in the fields and clicking submit, I get a "Success!" message that the email was sent. However, the email never arrives in my inbox.

I've read numerous posts on here about this problem (seems to be pretty common) but everything I've tried does not work; even using `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` fails to print in the console, yet I still get a "Success!" message when submitting.

My settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

DEBUG = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
...
```

My views.py:

```
...
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
...
class AboutPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'database/templates/about.html'

def about(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['xxxx@hotmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, 'about.html', {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),
    ...
    ]
```

My about.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
...
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>
...
{% endblock %}
```

And my success.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
...
  <h1>Success!</h1>
  <p>Thank you for your message!</p>
...
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

After running django-shell, per @YevheniiM's suggestion, here is what I got (it was too long to post in the comments):

```
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('subject', 'message', 'example@example.org', ['test@example.org'])
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: subject
From: example@example.org
To: test@example.org
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2019 23:33:35 -0000
Message-ID: <157100961593.25849.16400852689643226474@localhost>

message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
>>>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('subject', 'message', 'example@example.org', ['test@example.org'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/meganmccarty/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/meganmccarty/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/meganmccarty/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/meganmccarty/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 70, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MN2PR01CA0032.prod.exchangelabs.com]')
>>>
```

**EDIT 3**
For anyone reading this, it turns out that pythonanywhere and hotmail (both of which I was trying to use here) don't work together. Thank you for solving this, @YevheniiM! After switching to using a gmail account, everything is working perfectly!

Comment: When you tried with `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` the email doesn't come to your console either?

Comment: Your ```try ... except``` part doesn't work because you check only ```BadHeaderError```. Therefore you always see success page. Try change your code to ```except Exception as e: print(e)``` and see output.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Yes, when trying ```django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend```, nothing prints in the console. I realize that this might be due to the fact that I'm using PythonAnywhere for coding my web app and not having the web app on my local machine

Comment: @YevheniiM I tried changing the code as you suggested, but I ended up with a syntax error. Also, the code in question was something I found on two different tutorials regarding django contact forms (https://garethmoger.com/blog/post/14/django-contact-page-bootstrap and https://wsvincent.com/django-contact-form/)

Comment: @megan which versions of django/python you use?

Comment: Because even with ```django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend``` you have no output and response is your success url, I believe that problem with your ```try ... catch``` block. Also did you defined ```LOGGING``` in your ```settings.py``` file?

Comment: @YevheniiM. Thank you for your help on this! I'm using Django 2.2.6 and Python 3.7. And no, I haven't defined ```LOGGING``` in my ```settings.py```

Comment: @megan you know how to work with [```django shell```](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#shell)? 1. Change your ```EMAIL_BACKEND``` to ```django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend``` and comment all other email-related settings. 2. Open your PythonAnywhere console and navigate to your project directory (where ```manage.py``` file is located). Then run ```python3 manage.py shell```. You'll see python shell but with django context. Import ```sendmail``` by ```from django.core.mail import send_mail``` and try send mail in shell.

Comment: Like this: ```send_mail('subject', 'message', 'example@example.org', ['test@example.org'])```. Did you get any output after this?

Comment: Some how at `send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['xxxx@hotmail.com'])` line, could you print the `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting? just in case other settings might override it.

Comment: Yes, here is what I got: [posted above, too long for the comments]

Comment: @megan great, now try to change your settings to ```EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'``` and uncomment other lines. Exit from ```django shell``` (this is important for context reloading) and repeat step 2 that you done before. You'll get some error.

Comment: @megan judging by [this SO question (see updates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543475/django-email-sending-error) Pythonanywhere doesn't allow you work with hotmail, only gmail (or hotmail doesn't work such way). So solution - use gmail mail instead. But you need to change permissions on your gmail account [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I'm not sure how to do that exactly. Would I import my settings and add a line something like ```print(settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)```?

Comment: @YevheniiM. Thank you so much for the link! I'll try using gmail and change my permissions to see if that works

Comment: @megan because you use pythonanywhere and can't see development server console, then you need setup ```LOGGING``` in your ```settings.py``` to store logs in some file that you can read later (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/) for details). Or you can setup [Sentry](https://sentry.io/for/django/) for this purpose.

Comment: Yes you should setup a logger follow @YevheniiM. suggestion. But if you haven't done it yet, you could use template to work around to solve the issue first. `from django.conf import settings    def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html', {'mail_backend':settings.EMAIL_BACKEND})` then on your `success.html`, add this `{{ mail_backend }}` to see the value.

Comment: @megan I'm sorry, in your Step 2 with ```EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'``` you need to change mails in line ```send_mail('subject', 'message', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['xxxx@hotmail.com'])``` and import ```from django.conf import settings``` before this line. Maybe it will work with hotmail too.

Comment: Also I just realized that you trying to send mail ***from*** user of your website, which credentials you don't know. You can send email only from mail that you defined in ```EMAIL_HOST_USER```.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo: Thank you for the response! I already got everything working with gmail though, but I appreciate you taking the time to comment on my question. Will definitely look into setting up a logger

Comment: @YevheniiM. I actually tried what you suggested based on another thread I found on SO, but it didn't work (so I really doubt hotmail will work at this point). And I realize you're right, when I received the test email, it looked as though I sent it to myself (I used a different "from" address to test it). I guess that means I'll have to have the user leave their email in a different place (maybe in the body of the message) so I can respond to them

Comment: glad to hear that you solved it :)..